# how to optimize mysql query in phalcon

Tags: mysql, phalcon

i used this query:

```
$brands = TblBrand::find(array("id In (Select p.brand_id From EShop\\Models\\TblProduct as p Where p.id In (Select cp.product_id From EShop\\Models\\TblProductCategory as cp Where cp.group_id_1='$id'))", "order" => "title_fa asc"));
            if($brands != null and count($brands) > 0)
            {
                foreach($brands as $brand)
                {
                    $brandInProductCategory[$id][] = array
                    (
                        "id" => $brand->getId(),
                        "title_fa" => $brand->getTitleFa(),
                        "title_en" => $brand->getTitleEn()
                    );
                }
            }
```

> TblBrand => 110 records
>
> TblProduct => 2000 records
>
> TblProductCategory => 2500 records

when i used this code, my site donot show and loading page very long time ...
but when i remove this code, my site show.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you dump the whole query?As far as I can see,you have subquery in subquery which is prone to be slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your query. You are using the `IN` statement in a nested format, and that is always going to be slower than anything else. MySQL will need to first evaluate what is in the IN statement, return that and then do it all over again for the next level of records.

Try simplifying your query. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Brands
INNER JOIN Products ON Brand.id = Products.brand_id
INNER JOIN ProductCategory ON ProductCategory.product_id = Products.id
WHERE ProductCategory.group_id_1 = $id
```

To achieve the above, you can either use the Query Builder and get the results that way

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html

or if you have set up relationships in your models between brands, products and product categories, you can use that.

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/model-relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
$Brands = Brands::query()
->innerJoin("Products", "Products.brand_id = Brand.id")
->innerJoin("ProductCategory", "ProductCategory.product_id = Products.id")
->where("ProductCategory.group_id_1 = :group_id:")
->bind(["group_id" => $id])
->cache(["key" => __METHOD__.$id] // if defined modelCache as DI service 
->execute();
$brandInProductCategory[$id] = [];
foreach($Brands AS $Brand) {
array_push($brandInProductCategory[$id], [
    "id" => $Brand->getId(),
    "title_fa" => $Brand->getTitleFa(),
    "title_en" => $Brand->getTitleEn()
]);
}
```